# E185: Cannot find color scheme 'solarized.vim'

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vim, colors

I installed vim on Xubuntu with solarized scheme color.
It was working fine until I install  Pathogen.
Now, I keep getting the following error messahe while staring Vim in a terminal :

Error detected while processing /usr/share/vim/vimrc:
line   42:
E185: Cannot find color scheme 'solarized.vim'

Actually, the color scheme is still running despite this error message.

there is below the arborescence and the .vimrc file.

```
/home/marc/.vim/
/home/marc/.vim/autoload/
/home/marc/.vim/autoload/pathogen.vim

/home/marc/.vim/bundle/
/home/marc/.vim/bundle/solarized/
/home/marc/.vim/bundle/solarized/colors/solarized.vim

/home/marc/.vim/bundle/vim-sensible/
/home/marc/.vim/bundle/vim-sensible/.git/
/home/marc/.vim/bundle/vim-sensible/plugin/sensible.vim
```

Thanks for your help.

**.vimrc file**

```
call pathogen#infect()


set nocompatible


syntax on
filetype plugin indent on


set title                 

set number                
set ruler                
set wrap                  

set scrolloff=3            


set ignorecase            
set smartcase             

set incsearch             

set hlsearch              


set visualbell            
set noerrorbells          


set backspace=indent,eol,start


set hidden






let g:solarized_termcolors=256
"let g:solarized_visibility="high"
"let g:solarized_contrast ="high"
set t_Co=16
set background=dark
colorscheme solarized
highlight Normal ctermbg=NONE
highlight nonText ctermbg=NONE
set guifont=DejaVu\ Sans\ Mono\ 10
set antialias
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I also faced the same problem and
This is resolved by copying the file below to the colors directory.

```
cp ~/.vim/bundle/vim-colors-solarized/colors/solarized.vim ~/.vim/colors/
```

Answer (score 4):

Your `vimrc` is supposed to be here:

```
$HOME/.vimrc
```

or there, if you use Vim 7.4 or newer:

```
$HOME/.vim/vimrc
```

Never, *never*, **never** do anything Vim-related outside of `$HOME`.

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for the clarification.

 I moved the folder. vim from /home/marc/.vim/   to   /home/.vim/

I moved also the file .vimrc to /home/.vim /vimrc

But I still have the same error message.

7.4 is currently installed

Comment: No. You didn't get it; `$HOME` is a variable representing your "home" directory. You should have `/home/marc/.vim/` and `/home/marc/.vim/vimrc`.

Comment: same error , I added a screenshot in the bottom of my post to show the directory path.